# Почему код не работает? Надо найти сумму a и b используя sum() на питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def s(a,b):
    return sum(a,b)
n=s(int(input()), int(input()))
print(n)
```

Comment: поставьте `return a+b` или return sum((a,b)). Функция sum работает только с итерируемыми объектами - списками и тп

Answer (score 2):

Потому что, [sum(iterable[, start])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) принимает в себя коллекцию, т.е. то, что можно перебрать.

Можно сделать без `sum`:

```
a, b = int(input()), int(input())
print(a + b)
```

Или с `sum`:

```
a, b = int(input()), int(input())
print(sum((a, b)))
```

Или в одну строку:

```
print(sum((int(input()), int(input()))))
```

---

Еще пример:

- `sum(1, 2)` -- это ошибка, т.к. `1` нельзя итерировать
- `sum((1, 2))` или `sum([1, 2])` -- выведет `3`, т.к. обоих случаях используется то, что можно итерировать. В первом это кортеж (tuple), во втором список (list)
- `sum(map(int, "1234"))` выведет `10`, т.к. `1+2+3+4=10`. Функция `map` будет перебирать по элементно строку (контейнер), применит к каждому элементу функцию `int`, а `sum` все это сложит
- `sum(map(int, "1 2 3 4".split()))` выведет `10`, а так аналогично выше, но в `map` вернется список, полученный из разделения строки по пробелам